# JavaScript var=key not working?

Tags: javascript

anybody have an idea what is happening with this i've got the code

```
console.log('cCP: '+chatCurrentPlace+' - key: '+key); 
if(key>chatCurrentPlace){chatCurrentPlace=key;} 
console.log('cCP: '+chatCurrentPlace+' - key: '+key);
```

and the console logs

```
cCP: 0 - key: 4 
cCP: 4 - key: 4 
cCP: 4 - key: 7 
cCP: 7 - key: 7 
cCP: 7 - key: 8 
cCP: 8 - key: 8 
cCP: 8 - key: 9 
cCP: 9 - key: 9 
cCP: 9 - key: 11 
cCP: 9 - key: 11
```

why is the last one not working? it should be cCP: 11 - key: 11

Comment: Looks like you are comparing strings instead of numbers. `"9">"11"` is true.

Comment: I agree with @freakish . you can check `typeof key`

Comment: Just to put it in more detail... when comparing strings it compares them character by character. So `("9" > "11")` is actually `(9 > 1)`.

Comment: i worked it out the last key was a string of 11 instead of a digit for some reason :-/

Comment: ohhh they are all strings lol that makes sense ok thanks guys :-) i just made it (key>(chatCurrentPlace*1)) and all is well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One or both of your variables are probably strings, so are being compared as strings and no numbers. `"9" > "11"` for the same reason that `"b" > "aa"` (strings are compared character by character until the first index where they differ).

Convert the values to numbers in your test (e.g. with the [Unary + Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6)) :

```
if( +key > +chatCurrentPlace ){ chatCurrentPlace = key; }
```

or [the `parseInt` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2):

```
if( parseInt(key, 10) > parseInt(chatCurrentPlace, 10) ){ chatCurrentPlace = key; }
```

You may wish to convert the values before reaching the `if` so that they remain numbers throughout.

Comment: thanks I didn't know you could convert to digit using + I normally use  (something*1) but I prefer the +

Comment: IMHO both are ugly because they hide what they do too much, making the code harder to read. I prefer using `Number()`. Yes, it's a bit more to type, but good code is readable code, not short code.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the key and cCP values are not taken as strings? It looks like they are sorted alphabetically, unlike numbers.
Try

```
key = parseInt(key,10);
```

for both of the variables before comparing them.

Comment: Using `parseInt` (which needs a Upper Case `I`) without a radix is almost always a bad idea.